# Slot Machine Randomise

Tags: java, random, jtextfield, slot

I am creating a slot machine project(for fun).I am displaying the fruits in a JTextField. I have managed to display random fruits in the JTextFields, but the random fruits are the same, for example, the result would be -> Orange, Orange, Orange. Or it would be, Kiwi, Kiwi, Kiwi. ETC.
Here is my code.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;...

    import java.util.Random;


    public class Game extends JFrame {

    String [] fruits = { "Cherry", "Lemon", "Orange", "Grape", "Kiwi" };

    String fruit = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField Slot_1;
    private JTextField Slot_2;
    private JTextField Slot_3;

    /**
    * Launch the application.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Game frame = new Game();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }

    /**
    * Create the frame.
    */
    public Game() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    Slot_1 = new JTextField();
    Slot_1.setText("----------------");
    Slot_1.setEditable(false);
    Slot_1.setBounds(41, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_1);
    Slot_1.setColumns(10);

    Slot_2 = new JTextField();
    Slot_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    Slot_2.setText("-----------------");
    Slot_2.setEditable(false);
    Slot_2.setColumns(10);
    Slot_2.setBounds(183, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_2);

    Slot_3 = new JTextField();
    Slot_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    Slot_3.setText("---------------");
    Slot_3.setEditable(false);
    Slot_3.setColumns(10);
    Slot_3.setBounds(317, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_3);

    JButton btn_Pull = new JButton("Pull");
    btn_Pull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Slot_1.setText(fruit);
            Slot_2.setText(fruit);
            Slot_3.setText(fruit);

        }
    });
    btn_Pull.setBounds(145, 108, 166, 29);
    contentPane.add(btn_Pull);

    JButton btnMenu = new JButton("Menu");
    btnMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    btnMenu.setBounds(383, 243, 61, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnMenu);




}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: @soumya-r: Please do not make superfluous edits like this that add unnecessary or inappropriate bolding or highlighting to the question content.

Comment: Don't use JTextField to display the text. Use a JLabel. In the future you could even use an Icon to display the fruits in the label.

Answer (score 3):

```
String fruit = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
```

The value of fruit is fixed at the start of your class.

```
        Slot_1.setText(fruit);
        Slot_2.setText(fruit);
        Slot_3.setText(fruit);
```

The value of fruit doesn't change just because you assign it to 3 different text fields.

If you want random values then you need to invoke the random() method 3 time. Maybe something like:

```
Slot_1.setText( fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)] );
...
```

Or create a method that returns a random string:

```
private String getFruit()
{
    return fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
}
```

and use:

```
slot_1.setText( getFruit() );
```

Also:

1. Variable names should not start with an upper case character (Slot_1...). Your other variables are correct (fruits, fruit) so be consistent.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Slot_1.setText(fruit);
Slot_2.setText(fruit);
Slot_3.setText(fruit);
```

You expect these the magically change somehow? `fruit` is simply a string variable, and you only set it once at the top of your class. You need to call the `Math.random()` function for each slot. You could do this by making `fruit` a function that got the random number and produced a new fruit each time, then you'd replace `fruit` above by `fruit()`. Or you could just copy the simple code line from the top int the lines here.

Answer (score 0):

add a function to your class called generateFruit();

```
private String generateFruit()
{
    return this.fruits[(int) (Math.random() * this.fruits.length)];
}
```

then call it instead of the set fruit variable.

```
Slot_1.setText(this.generateFruit());
```

Answer (score 0):

I also added in a method that changes fruit1, fruit2 and fruit3, and I call that method in the action listener that changes the values. This will change the values every time you push pull.

public class Game extends JFrame {
    String [] fruits = { "Cherry", "Lemon", "Orange", "Grape", "Kiwi" };

```
String fruit1 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
String fruit2 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
String fruit3 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField Slot_1;
private JTextField Slot_2;
private JTextField Slot_3;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Game frame = new Game();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Game() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    Slot_1 = new JTextField();
    Slot_1.setText("----------------");
    Slot_1.setEditable(false);
    Slot_1.setBounds(41, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_1);
    Slot_1.setColumns(10);

    Slot_2 = new JTextField();
    Slot_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    Slot_2.setText("-----------------");
    Slot_2.setEditable(false);
    Slot_2.setColumns(10);
    Slot_2.setBounds(183, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_2);

    Slot_3 = new JTextField();
    Slot_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    Slot_3.setText("---------------");
    Slot_3.setEditable(false);
    Slot_3.setColumns(10);
    Slot_3.setBounds(317, 53, 95, 28);
    contentPane.add(Slot_3);

    JButton btn_Pull = new JButton("Pull");
    btn_Pull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Slot_1.setText(fruit1);
            Slot_2.setText(fruit2);
            Slot_3.setText(fruit3);
            newRandomPullValues();
        }
    });
    btn_Pull.setBounds(145, 108, 166, 29);
    contentPane.add(btn_Pull);

    JButton btnMenu = new JButton("Menu");
    btnMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    btnMenu.setBounds(383, 243, 61, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnMenu);




}

public void newRandomPullValues() {
    fruit1 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
    fruit2 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
    fruit3 = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
}
```

}

Comment: Basic concept of invoking random multiple times has already been given. `This will change the values every time you push pull.` - Not the best implementation. Normally you would invoke the method BEFORE you set the text, not after for a couple of reasons: 1) keep the values of the variables consistent with the display value in the text field. 2) If you have a method to assign the values then you should always invoke that method as oppose to invoking the random process three separate times when the class is created. Keep the randomizing logic in one place.

Comment: I agree, it was just a quick implementation. I would def use his advice OP.